Converting the output of LT8292 to negative value
I want to design a variable output DC-DC converter to convert 12V to -1V to -20V at 4A, would you please let me know if I can make changes on the following schematic to achieve this (LT8292)?

If not would you please introduce a relevant chip and correct schematic or reference design for this?

That's not an inverting converter nor a flyback converter controller, so, while it's technically possible by adding clever inverting feedback and convert it to a flyback converter architecture without the chip "noticing", that would a lot of complexity and cost to your schematic: You chose the wrong component with the Buck-Boost (non-inverting) LT8292. No sense in trying to shoehorn it into something it isn't, if the cost of that shoehorning exceed the cost of buying something more sensibly designed for your use case.
Note that 20 V at 4 A means pretty significant power: 80 W. You'd do well using a design from the ground up to reflect that. Hans links to two approaches there.
Note that my assessment here is that you underestimate complexity of your endeavour. Getting 80W through requires a relatively bulky transformer (if your flyback tag is to be taken seriously), or very high switching frequency and efficient transistors. (I don't even want to think about whether this low-absolute-voltage-ratio inverting power requirement would best be served with a multi-phase converter, and whether these are a thing for flybacks.)

There are tools like the power designer from TI: https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/ which are made to guide you in the power process.
If you want to stay with analog devices, they also have a portfolio of inverting regulators: https://www.analog.com/en/product-category/inverting-regulators.html#products-in-category
